# Minimum load for bridge rectifier?

Tags: led, low-power

I need to convert 12VAC to 12VDC. If I use a bridge rectifier, is there a minimum output load required for the rectifier to function? I don’t see that on data sheets. My LEDs will present ~30W.

Comment: In addition to current limiting, 30 Watts is about enough to ponder *harmonic content* & *gap fill*.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no minimum load for a bridge rectifier.

When powering your LEDs, make sure that there's something to limit the current (series resistor or a constant-current LED driver). You might also want to add a smoothing capacitor after the rectifier to eliminate flickering (there are online calculators for sizing the capacitor).